# Strings in C, &str

Tags: c, pointers

I came across this question:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 char str[25]="Catch me, if u can!";
 printf("%s\n",&str+2);
 return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain me the meaning of `&str+2`? How does this work?

Answer (score 5):

`&str` returns a pointer of type `char (*)[25]`. That means, the size of the memory pointed to by this pointer will be `sizeof(str)`, i. e. 25. According to normal pointer arithmetic, adding 2 to this value will result in a pointer of type `char (*)[25]` that will point 25 bytes past the end of the `str` array. Printing it is most probably undefined behavior.

Comment: Actually, you do not even need to print it to get undefined behavior; merely evaluating `&str+2` is undefined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I meant, 'using' :) Of course, as we all know, pointer arithmetic that operates on or results in an invalid pointer is undefined even if the memory behind it is never actually accessed (but here it's even worse, since it is accessed, indeed - am I seeing right that this program invokes undefined behavior twice in a row?)

Comment: But printing does not modify memory. So what's so bad about it?

Comment: @H2CO3: We cannot state whether the program invokes undefined behavior after the first invocation of undefined behavior, since it is undefined what happens after the first invocation. :-)

Comment: @EricPostpischil We should tag this question with "language-agnostic", after all :P

Comment: @möter: There are two levels on which to answer this question. On the practical implementation level, printing will read the memory, and the memory might not be mapped, and a trap may occur. Or, the memory may be filled with non-null characters, so the `printf` will go on printing an enormous number of characters, until a null is reached or a trap occurs. It is even possible for a C implementation to get some fault merely calculating `&str+2`, although this does not occur in common implementations. On the C standard level, the standard explicitly states this is undefined behavior.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I gotta look further into this, thanks for the pointers (pun intended)

Comment: @EricPostpischil can or will this cause a segmentation fault / runtime error?

Comment: @Amitd yes, it can. It's not guaranteed to do so (actually, on my machine, it prints some random chars and exits successfully), but it most likely will.

Comment: @Amitd: It can, and it will in some situations. If you change `char str[25]=…` to `char str[2500]=…`, or another large value, you are likely to get a segmentation fault, as the pointed-to address will be outside the stack. 25 is likely small enough to merely point to a different place within the stack.

Answer (score 4):

`str` is an expression that has type “array of 25 char”. In most contexts, an array is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. Thus, in `str+2`, `str` is converted to a pointer to the first `char` in the array, and, when 2 is added, the result is a pointer to the third `char` in the array.

However, according to C 2011 6.3.2.1 3, when an expression of array type is the operand of `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, this automatic conversion does not occur. Thus, in `&str+2`, `str` is not converted to a pointer; it remains an array of 25 char. Then `&str` is a pointer to an array of 25 char. When 2 is added to this, the result is, conceptually, a pointer to the third element of an array of arrays of 25 char.

However, pointer arithmetic is only defined inside an array, up to a fictional element at the end of the array. (Additionally, for the purposes of pointer arithmetic, single objects are treated as an array with one element.) Since we have only one array of 25 char and not an array of arrays of 25 char, there is no third element to point to, and `&str+2` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what you are doing there will result in undefined behaviour at best.

`str` is a symbol which relates to the memory address on your stack where the string starts. `&str` is invalid on a stack symbol and using that will result in undefined behaviour. What you probably wanted is `str + 2` which is a pointer to the 3rd byte in the string, thus

```
printf("%s\n",str+2);
```

will print `"tch me, if u can!\n"`

Comment: "&str is invalid on a stack symbol" - it isn't. (Oh, and I didn't downvote this one, to be clear.)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with taking the address of an object with automatic storage duration (such as objects on the stack) or with using that address during the object’s lifetime.

Comment: Right.  The only real problem with pointers to auto objects occurs when the object is destroyed (or, rather, when you leave the scope where the object was defined); then the pointer points at FSM-knows-what.  As long as you don't let such a pointer exist outside that scope (for example, by returning it or storing it somewhere non-auto), you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you define your array:

```
char str[25] = "Catch me, if you can!";
```

What you're getting is 25 bytes of spaced reserved on the stack with the following put in it:

```
@Address                                                                @Address 
0xbfa7fc13                                                             0xbfa7fc2C
 |                                                                          | 
 V                                                                          V
[C][a][t][c][h][ ][m][e][,][ ][i][f][ ][y][o][u][ ][c][a][n][!][\0][\0][\0][\0]
```

Looking at the address of str:

```
printf("%#x, %#x\n", str, &str);
```

You're going to see `0xbfa7fc13`, `0xbfa7fc13`. Same value, because the array starts at it's address. When you add 2 to str you'll be pointing further down the string:

```
0xbfa7fc13 + 2 = 
    0xbfa7fc15
        |
        V
       [t][c][h][ ][m][e][,][ ][i][f][ ][y][o][u][ ][c][a][n][!][\0][\0][\0][\0]
```

So printing:

```
printf("%s\n", str+2);
```

Will just dump the string a little further down. However if you add 2 to the address of `str`, then it will automagiclly * that for you by the size of whatever you're adding:

```
&str + 2 ==> &str + 2 * sizeof(str) ==> &str + 50 ==> 0xbfa7fc45
```

As you can see that address is way past where your array is on the stack, so printing:

```
printf("%s\n",&str+2);
```

Will just spit out whatever garbage is 50 bytes past your array until a `'\0'` is found, if you're lucky. It's undefined behavior, so it can do pretty much anything.

Comment: Will *probably* just spit out garbage.  It could also segfault.  Or trigger some other error.  Hell, as far as the standard specifies, it could order a dozen pizzas on your credit card if it wanted.

Comment: @cHao - That's UB for ya... maybe I'll give it a try, I could go for some pizza...